# Canonical way to do bulk create in django-rest-framework 3.x?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In 2.x we had a serializer which looked like:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bar = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
```

This effectively was able to handle bulk creates (passing a `list` as the body of a JSON post request). In 3.x, this endpoint is broken. I've tried to implement something [similar to the docs on DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-create)

```
class FooListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        foos = [Foo(**item) for item in validated_data]
        return Foo.objects.bulk_create(foos)

class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bar = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Bar.objects.all()
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        list_serializer_class = FooListSerializer
```

And while this works for a single create request, when I attempt to pass a list I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'FooListSerializer' object has no attribute 'object'
```

I've seen some hacks where `__init__` is super'd, but it seems with the creation of the `ListSerializer` class in 3.x there has to be a cleaner way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to post/put json data to ListSerializer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27871396/359284). You can find my detailed answer there, with examples for how to handle bulk create/update/delete.

Comment: Actually I was just about to comment on your very question - your solution worked for me (thanks a ton), and I do believe these are related, but I suspect that the "canonical" solution has actually not been implemented yet?

Comment: I should mention that your previous way has been broken since 2.4, when DRF removed the ability for a list to be interpreted as `many=True` automatically.

Comment: Yeah we were actually using the Bulk mixin on the associated viewset to force it to work

Comment: Late to the party but suggest marking the question as answered if you have a solution - took me a while to spot your comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i bulk create in django rest serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33826742/how-can-i-bulk-create-in-django-rest-serializer)

Answer (score 8):

You don't show how your code is making a `FooSerializer` instance. The [Django REST Framework 3 documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects) says:

> To serialize a queryset or list of objects instead of a single object instance, you should pass the `many=True` flag when instantiating the serializer. You can then pass a queryset or list of objects to be serialized.

So, it seems that your code should detect whether the data contains one instance or many, and:

- `serializer = FooSerializer()` to handle one instance, or
- `serializer = FooSerializer(many=True)` to handle a list of many instances.

Explicit is better than implicit :-)

Comment: The documentation link now 404s, you can find the updated link here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects

Comment: Boo, documentation URLs should not change. Thanks for the note @raphaël-gomès, I have updated the answer now.