# How can i bulk create in django rest serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I used to use **allow_add_remove=True** which was availabe in django rest 2.0  for writing nestable serializer but its not available in 3.0 and i am having hard time implementing it.

I want to do something like this

```
class UserSerialzier():
    project = ProjectSerilaizer(many=True, allow_add_remove=True, read_only=False)


class ProjectSerialzier():
    ideas = IdeaSerilaizer(many=True, allow_add_remove=True, read_only=False)
    sources = SourceSerilaizer(many=True, allow_add_remove=True, read_only=False)

class IdeaSerialzier():
    pass

class SourceSerialzier():
    pass
```

Now i am not able to know how can i implement the allow_add_remove behavior in DRF 3.0

I am confused that do i need to override `create` and `update` method of UserSerializer

or i need  to create separate IdeaListSerializer  for every model

```
class IdeaListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        ideas = [Idea(**item) for item in validated_data]
        return Ideas.objects.bulk_create(books)
```

Comment: What is the main object that you want to add? could you add your JSON request, please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you do need to override `create` and `update` methods of your `UserSerializer`.

I've spent a lot of time trying to make nested writable serializers work with DRF 2.x and the more I fixed issues the more issues were risen with corner use cases.

Therefore Tom decided that it should be left up to the developer to handle the creation and updates.

The [documentation provides an example](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) for a 1 nesting level creation but it's the same for update and/or with more nesting level

Comment: I want to know that in create do i need to create bulk objects or single object. if i create bulk objects then ehy do i need listSeriaizer

Comment: Please be more precise when you are saying bulk object. Which ones are referring to ? You don't need `ListSerializer` since the `many=True` creates a ListSerializer behind the scene.

Comment: Thanks for that. Ok i got that i don't need to use LIstSerializer if i use many=True. That solve my one problem. Now my questions was u told me that i have to ovewrite create method. Now my confusion was. In that created method of UserSerializer do i need to `Projects.objects.bulk_create(projects)` and in create method of Project serializer , do i need to use  `Ideas.objects.bulk_create(ideas)` and `sources.objects.bulk_create(sources)`

Comment: You need to do all the creations / updates / deletions in the top serializer create / update method - i.e. just on the UserSerializer only. The nested serializer's create / update aren't call by DRF because it doesn't assume what to do at all

Comment: Thanks , now i got the system working. Do you know by chance where in DRF 2.0 is the code for allow_add_remove(). because i wanted to copy that in DRF3.0. I think just by that flag my code for create / update will be removed from all serilizers. I really want to abstract that logic rather than put in every serilaizer

Comment: @Linovia How to do bulk_create with ignoring duplicates or even by writing raw sql query?