# Django REST Framework Serialization POST is slow

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am running on Django 2.1.1 and Python 3.6.5 and am performing a reasonably large POST operation (32,000 JSON objects). I have the following:

Model:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    investigation = models.ForeignKey(Investigation)
    usage = models.FloatField()
    sector = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='')
    cost = models.FloatField()
    demand = models.FloatField()
```

Serializer:

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = ('investigation', 'usage', 'sector', 'cost', 'demand')
```

View:

```
class DataView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    def create(self, request, pk, format=None):
        data_serializer = DataSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        if data_serializer.is_valid():
            data_serializer.save()
```

The problems come at both the is_valid() and save() steps which each fire off a separate query for each of the 32,000 objects.

I've spent a long time looking into the issue and I'm guessing that the is_valid() step is slow because of the N+1 query problem since the foreign key is being looked up each time (although I could be wrong about this!) but I have no idea how to implement the prefetch_related method in this framework.

The save() step (which is the slowest part) obviously needs to be done in one query (probably a bulk_create) but I can't find where to add the bulk_create step in. I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33826742/how-can-i-bulk-create-in-django-rest-serializer) but am still none the wiser from the answer. I tried to create a ListSerializer as the question suggests but the objects still seemed to be serialized one by one.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might help you to check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37329771/django-rest-bulk-post-post-array-of-json-objects).

Comment: @AuroraWang I don't think this helps. There is still a query for every validation step and for every creation. I think that this is just a different way of having `many = True` in your view.

Comment: @Tom Did you find a solution eventually?

Comment: @darcyy Follow pradeepcep's solution.

Comment: Better late than never @Tom, have a look at my SO-post where I solved the N+1 validation problem in is_valid(). I demonstrate how it would be done when you want to post an item with a foreign key using it's name instead of the ID-pk, however I also had it working using just the ID from the primary key.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67111304/drf-selected-related-on-is-valid

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to perform a Django ORM `bulk_create()` after you validate the data using your serializer. Your view will then look something like this:

```py
class DataView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    def create(self, request, pk, format=None):
        data_serializer = DataSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        if data_serializer.is_valid():
            data_objects = []
            for data_object_info in data_serializer.validated_data:
                data_objects.append(Data(**data_object_info))
            Data.objects.bulk_create(data_objects)
```

or just the following, if you want a one-liner:

```py
Data.objects.bulk_create([Data(**params) for params in data_serializer.validated_data])
```

If you don't want to clutter your view, then you can write a class or method that performs the validation (using the serializer) and creation. You can then use this inside the view.

Comment: Thanks @pradeepcep. This has significantly reduced the time taken for inserting the data into the database for my usecase.

Answer (score -1):

You can try by overriding the create method of serializer as follows:

```
def create(self, request):
    is_many = True if isinstance(request.data, list) else False

    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=is_many)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,headers=headers)
```

Comment: It seems to me as if you've just pasted code from the comment above which isn't very helpful. Please see my comment as to why this doesn't work.