# Passing List to Manytomany field in APIVIew having error "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I made APIs to create update case But the problem is with `task` if I pass only one pk like(task=1) while updating or creating through postman then it works fine and case will be created with referencing that task but a task is a manytomany field I need to assign multiple task pk to a case like `task = [1,2]` Then it is giving error like

```
        "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."
    ]
```

```
class Case(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    task = models.ManyToManyField('task.Task',blank=True, null=True)
    assigned_to = models.ForeignKey("account.User",null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class CaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Case
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'task', 'assigned_to')
class CaseCreateView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    @access_permission('case_create')
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = CaseSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class CaseUpdateView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    model = Case

    @access_permission('case_edit')
    def put(self, request,pk, format=None):
        case = get_object(self,pk)
        serializer = CaseSerializer(case,data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: create and update in DRF just for one object so if you want to bulk create/update you need to use trick for it . see this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33826742/how-can-i-bulk-create-in-django-rest-serializer
and there is a package for bulk in DRF but i never used it : https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework-bulk/

Comment: I want to assign multiple tasks to case as case have manytomany field for referencing @mehdi

Comment: so can you update your question with `view` part too?

Comment: Treid adding ```task = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True,read_only=False,queryset=Task.objects.all())``` in serializer still issue is persistant

Answer (score 0):

i'm new in DRF too and most of time i just using `Generic` but i will try maybe helping you. add `read_only_fields=(task, )` in your serializer and then we will adding `task`s to `Case` instance manually.by this way in create method we don't need to 'task' and serializer will be valid.
serializer.py:

```
class CaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Case
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'task', 'assigned_to')
        read_only_fields = ('task', )
```

```
class CaseUpdateView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    model = Case

    @access_permission('case_edit')
    def put(self, request,pk, format=None):
        case = get_object(self,pk)
        serializer = CaseSerializer(case,data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            task_id_list = request.data['tasks_id'] # depending on request
            for task_id in task_id_list: # this way we can add to M2M field manually  
                  task = Task.object.get(id=task_id)
                  case.task.add(task)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Solved it: the problem is in make request the API, not the code. And this one is just a workaround.