# Creating multiple model instances in DRF3

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

1) I would like to create multiple model instances with one API call, like asked here: [How do I create multiple model instances with Django Rest Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666199/how-do-i-create-multiple-model-instances-with-django-rest-framework)
I tried the solution named in the link, with no success.

I am trying to upload multiple files in one API call. 
Result: the files are uploaded (only once I overwrote perform_create) BUT only one instance is created (if I send two files, only the latter is created as an instance).

My code:

```
class FileUploadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        many = kwargs.pop('many', True)
        super(FileUploadSerializer, self).__init__(many=many, *args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = FileUpload
        read_only_fields = ('created', 'datafile', 'owner')

class FileUploadViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = FileUpload.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FileUploadSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser, )

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        file_list = self.request.data.getlist('file')
        for item in file_list:
            serializer.save(file=item)
```

Am I on the right track? The documentation http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects mentions: "To serialize a queryset or list of objects instead of a single object instance, you should pass the many=True flag when instantiating the serializer. You can then pass a queryset or list of objects to be serialized." => It should be possible ...

2) Is it better to use django-rest-framework-bulk for this? https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to post/put json data to ListSerializer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869841/how-to-post-put-json-data-to-listserializer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Django REST framework 3.1, it is not possible to submit multiple values using form data. This is because there is no standardized way of sending lists of data *with associations*, which is required for handling a `ListSerializer`.

There are plans to implement [HTML JSON forms](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2148) support, which would end up allowing this to work with a standard. That is milestoned for Django REST framework 3.2, but has not yet been completed.

---

Until then, it is recommended to use JSON instead of form data. JSON is supported for bulk creation and updating, [and you can read about how to impelement it here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27869841/359284). The alternative is to [use django-rest-framework-bulk](https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk) which can do the same.

In order to upload a file using JSON, you would need to base64-encode the file and use [a custom `Base64ImageField`](https://github.com/Hipo/drf-extra-fields) to allow them to be uploaded. This is because [JSON does not natively support file uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10492617/359284).

Comment: Ok, thanks for this. The doc didn't make this clear to me - will try and use DRF - bulk!

Comment: By the way, is it a good idea to bulk upload several base64 encoded zip files ? One zip can be around 3 - 5 MB.

Comment: Nope, probably not. Many web servers will reject requests over a certain size limit (10-25MB). This isn't special to sending files over JSON (though the requests are larger), you would hit similar limitations with a standard file upload.