# how to update in a single post multiple instances - django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, axios

I have array objects:

```
const ordsend =[
    {
      order: 4,
      id: 1,
    },
    {
      order: 2,
      id: 2,
    }
]
```

where **id** is the primary key,
That for axios I am sending this by the **POST** method:

```
this.axios.post('route-dispatchs/order/', this.ordsend)
   .then((response) => {
     console.log(success);
});
```

this seems right to me because through this filtering by the **id** and updating its respective **order**

```
class RouteDispatchViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = RouteDispatch.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RouteDispatchSerializer

    @list_route(methods=['post'], url_path='order')
def order_dispatch(self, request):
    for data in request.data:
        self.queryset.filter(id=data['id']).update(order=data['order'])

    page = self.paginate_queryset(self.queryset)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
    serializer = self.get_serializer(self.queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

but unfortunately it shows me the following error:

**AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'**

How can I do a multiple update in a single request?

error:

[image]

when I send only one :

```
this.ordsend[0]
```

and I remove the ** for ** updates perfectly.

Comment: I have described an alternative in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59756993/7392069

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a request payload as below,

```
{'payload' :[
    {
        "order": 4,
        "id": 1,
    },
    {
        "order": 2,
        "id": 2,
    }
]}
```

then try to change your `views` as  below,

```
class RouteDispatchViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = RouteDispatch.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RouteDispatchSerializer

    @list_route(methods=['post'], url_path='order')
    def order_dispatch(self, request):
        for data in request.data['payload']:
            self.queryset.filter(id=data['id']).update(order=data['order'])

        page = self.paginate_queryset(self.queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(self.queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Refference : [Queryset update django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#update)

Comment: Thank you very much but it does not work ... it shows me the following error: **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'**
Update the question with your suggestion