# Django REST Framework: Serializer to update object if it exists (by unique together)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have model **Run**. It represents a time period measurement of data:

```
class Run(models.Model):
    start_time      = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    end_time        = models.DateTimeField()
    chamber         = models.ForeignKey(Chamber, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together=(('start_time', 'chamber'),)
```

Here is an example of a POST request data blurb for this endpoint:

```
{
    "start_time": "2018-11-11T12:00:00Z",
    "end_time": "2018-11-11T12:00:01Z",
    "chamber": "My Test Chamber"
}
```

A **Run** belongs to a **Chamber** and has a **start_time** and **end_time**

A **Run** cannot share the same **Chamber** and **start_time**. If I get the same **start_time** and **Chamber** in my request data blurb, that means the **Run** is still ongoing and needs to be updated.

When the request comes through the first time, I create a **Run** object, that works fine. The sensor that is sending the requests will then send the same POST request data blurb, changing only the **end_time** of the data blurb, as long as a "**Run**" is ongoing.

The sensor does not send PUT or PATCH, it only sends POST, this may be a problem, but it's unfixable so I have to make do with POST requests.

The behaviour I desire is:

1. The first time a **Run** data blurb is sent, create a new **Run** object
2. As long as I receive the same **Chamber** and **run_start** in a data blurb, (check that this combination exists), update that **Run**'s **end_time** (a **Run** is ongoing)

Here is Serializer:

```
class RunsCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Run
        fields = [
            'id',
            'chamber',
            'start_time',
            'end_time'
        ]
```

Here is views.py on API endpoint:

```
class RunsCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Run.objects.all()
    queryset = queryset.prefetch_related('chamber')
    serializer_class = RunsCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            chamber = Chamber.objects.get(chamber_name=request.data["chamber"])
            request.data["chamber"] = chamber.id
        except:
            print("Invalid chamber name")

        serializer = RunsCreateSerializer(data=request.data)
        print(serializer)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

Now, I found I had to modify "**create**" on the views.py a little, as the sensor sends the **Chamber** as a string identifier. I then have to check that string against my **Chamber**s table and retrieve the object instance, then modify the request data  to substitute the **Chamber** string for its ID on my DB. I'm not sure if that is the right approach but it worked for me then.

Now for my attempt at fixing this:

On serializers.py:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    run, created = Run.objects.update_or_create(
                    chamber=validated_data.get('chamber'),
                    start_time=validated_data.get('start_time'),
                    end_time=validated_data.get('end_time'))
    return run

def update(self, run, validated_data):
    run.chamber = validated_data.get('chamber', run.chamber)
    run.start_time = validated_data.get('start_time', run.start_time)
    run.created = validated_data.get('created', run.created)
    run.save()
    return run
```

I thought by doing this on my serializer I would be able to update the object, but it doesn't seem to be reaching that point (tried with a print("Sanity check") on the create and update methods, I don't see my sanity check output, so I know I'm not reaching that point).

I suspect it has to do with me overriding the create method on the view, but I'm not sure.

If you know how to update the object, and possibly have the serializer/view handle a string for **Chamber** name instead of having to meddle with methods to replace strings for IDs, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Check out my answer to another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59756993/7392069

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned that you are getting `chamber` as a string, so to handle that relationship properly, use `chamber = serializer.StringRelatedField()` in your serializer. Remove any method which you have overridden in serializer/view. Just add the following in your `RunsCreateAPIView`.

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    chamber=serializer.validated_data.get('chamber'),
    start_time=serializer.validated_data.get('start_time')
    end_time=serializer.validated_data.get('end_time')
    Run.objects.update_or_create(
                  chamber=chamber, 
                  start_time=start_time, 
                  defaults = {"end_time": end_time}
                  )
```

`update_or_create` will automatically handle the creation or updating based on the value of chamber and start_time.

Answer (score 0):

we can simply override the method `def perform_create(self, serializer):`

```
class RunsCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
  # some code
  def perform_create(self, serializer):
    chamber=serializer.validated_data.get('chamber'),
    chamber = Chamber.objects.get(chamber_name=chamber)
    start_time=serializer.validated_data.get('start_time')
    end_time=serializer.validated_data.get('end_time'),

    obj_lst = Run.objects.filter(chamber=chamber, start_time=start_time)
    if obj_lst:
        obj_lst.update(
                chamber=chamber,
                start_time=start_time,
                end_time=end_time)
    else:
        Run.objects.create(chamber=chamber,
                start_time=start_time,
                end_time=end_time)
```

Comment: Am I using this instead of the create method? Alongside it? Inside it?

I tried this, but it's not working yet. If I commet out (my overriding of) the create method and just use this I get `"chamber": [
        "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."
    ]"` as the Sensor is passing a chamber name string, not the ID in the DB