# Django Rest Framework ListSerializer Partial Update

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm writing a serializer to provide multiple partial updates to a django model. I'm following the example implementation that appears in the DRF api guide, reproduced below and linked here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-update.

The following was retrieved from django-rest-framework documentation:

**serializer.py**

```
class BookListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # Maps for id->instance and id->data item.
        book_mapping = {book.id: book for book in instance}
        data_mapping = {item['id']: item for item in validated_data}

        # Perform creations and updates.
        ret = []
        for book_id, data in data_mapping.items():
            book = book_mapping.get(book_id, None)
            if book is None:
                ret.append(self.child.create(data))
            else:
                ret.append(self.child.update(book, data))

        # Perform deletions.
        for book_id, book in book_mapping.items():
            if book_id not in data_mapping:
                book.delete()

        return ret

class BookSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # We need to identify elements in the list using their primary key,
    # so use a writable field here, rather than the default which would be read-only.
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    ...

    class Meta:
        list_serializer_class = BookListSerializer
```

In my code I'm getting a **NotImplementedError('`update()` must be implemented.')** in my views.py when .save() is called on the serializer that is returned.

My understanding is that the ListsSerializer overrides the .update(), so could anyone help explain why I'm getting the NotImpletmentedError?

**views.py**

```
elif request.method == 'PATCH':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        books = Book.objects.all()
        # both partial and many set to True
        serializer = BookSerializer(books, data=data, partial=True, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Comment: Hi, is the LoadingPatchSerializer the one raising the error? Can you show it's implementation, please?

Comment: @luistm, sorry that should be the BookSerializer. I've edited it. The error is coming from serializer.save().

Comment: You need to override the method there on BookSerializer

Comment: @luistm, ah! that worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This solution did not work for me. I found another way to make it work, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59756993/7392069

Answer (score 2):

With the help of @luistm, I managed to solve this. Continuing with the DRF example above my implementation of the update() override in the bookSerializer class was as below.

**serializer.py**

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # We need to identify elements in the list using their primary key,
    # so use a writable field here, rather than the default which would be read-only.
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    ...

    class Meta:
        list_serializer_class = BookListSerializer

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
         """update the page number of the book and save"""
         instance.page = validated_data.get('page', instance.page)
         instance.save()
         return instance
```